# How can i change column value in sql query result, not in database?

Tags: sql

I have a table named user. In this table, there is a column named 'Sex', which has value `'m'` or `'f'`. I want to present these values as `'male'` or `'female'` without changing the exact value in the database. What is the best way?

Comment: Hint: `CASE` expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    Sex,
    CASE Sex WHEN 'm' THEN 'male'
             WHEN 'f' THEN 'female' END AS SexLabel
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CASE` expression since you have only `'m'` and `'f'`

```
SELECT
    Sex,
    CASE Sex WHEN 'm' THEN 'male'
             else 'female' END AS SexLabel
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: In reading your answer I experience a strange sense of deja-vu.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I copy the code from your answer and made the changes. It's not a plagiarism.

Comment: Assuming the `Sex` column might be `NULL` for some records, your logic would default them to being female.

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen but I'm assuming `Sex` is `NOT NULL` too :)